# error on eclipse Invalid location of tag (b)

Tags: html, eclipse, syntax

I start to work with eclipse debugger. I write a simple html file with two different lines.

```
<h3 id="TitleField">Array Function </h3><b />
<p><h1>array_change_key_case</h1></p>
```

I got Exclamation mark with "Invalid location of tag (h1)." and "Invalid location of tag (b).".
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With headers and paragraphs it automatically starts on a new line, so the `<br>` tag is not necessary. `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc. are titles, and `<p>` are paragraphs.

You post titles above paragraphs and not inside them, which would look like this:

```
<h1>array_change_key_case</h1>
<p>your text</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `P` can contain only inline elements not block elements like `H1`. 
   See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-P
2. `<b />` should be `<br />`

Comment: ok I change to '<p><h1>array_change_key_case</h1></p>' and '<h3 id="TitleField">Array Function </h3><br />' and I still have same

Comment: 'Invalid location of tag (br).' and 'Invalid location of tag (p).'

Comment: You don't need any `br` tag at all.