# Eclipse Warnings Invalid location tag on valid HTML5 tags

Tags: eclipse, html, validation, syntax, eclipse-neon

I'm getting *Invalid location tag* Warning on some tags with Eclipse Neon.3. For example:

```
<a ...><h1></h1></a>
```

is valid on HTML5 but eclipse showing *Invalid location tag* warning for `<H1>`.

I've seen another question on 
[Why does Eclipse creates warning on HTML script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268976/why-does-eclipse-creates-warning-on-html-script-tag). I don't know it's the same problem as this or not (that question is implying to the *Undefined attribute name* Warning). but asked on +6 years ago.

Another old Question (+5 years ago) with about the same problem: [error on eclipse Invalid location of tag (b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137033/error-on-eclipse-invalid-location-of-tag-b). *But it's not about how eclipse throw warning for **valid** HTML5 tags.*

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 7):

The stupid Eclipse does not fit HTML 5 syntax, although it's already at least 5 years after HTML 5 standard release out. The only way you can do is to force Eclipse "ignore" these warnings. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193905/warnings-of-valid-html5-attributes-in-eclipse/8104849).