# Why HTML tag not compatible in JSP file?

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to have a `<div>` tag inside `<a>` tag. I know that in HTML 4.1, this is invalid since the element inside must be inline element rather than block element. But in HTML 5, it is valid.

But in my JSP file, it gives me the warning: `Invalid location of tag (div)` even though I declared .

Is this because JSP does not support all features of HTML5?

I am using Tomcat 9, so I assume JSP version is 2.3 which is the latest.

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Oba.png)

Comment: Short Answer: you could change eclipse HTML validation. So far I know This is not related to JSP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742158/eclipse-warnings-invalid-location-tag-on-valid-html5-tags